# Apache POI enclosing area of UDF

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to write a UDF, that behaves differently when called inside an excel array. So when the call in Excel looks like this: {=MyFunction()} and spans multiple rows or columns, I would like to modify the whole area. For this I need to find out if the function is called for an area.
How can this be done? I can not find any method in the passed context...

I am looking for something like this:

```
new FreeRefFunction()
{
    @Override
    public ValueEval evaluate(ValueEval[] arg0, OperationEvaluationContext arg1)
    {
        if(arg1.isCalledInArray())
        {
            area = arg1.getArrayArea();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think array formula evaluation is supported in POI yet, though I could be wrong. To test this, use Excel to create a workbook with an array formula, open the workbook in POI, and evaluate the formula per https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html